How to load a SVG file into a TBitmap using Skia in Delphi 12.1, preserving transparency?
Skia is included in Delphi 12.
In a 32-bit Delphi 12.1 VCL Application in Windows 11, how to load an SVG file into a TBitmap using Skia preserving transparency?
I have researched this for many hours but could not find a proper solution.
I have only found out that when using Skia, TBitmap has a helper class, SkiaDraw:
bmp := TBitmap.Create;
bmp.SkiaDraw(...

When using this code, I get the error message "Invalid Bitmap":
bmp := TBitmap.Create;
try
  bmp.SkiaDraw(
    procedure(const ACanvas: System.Skia.ISKCanvas)
    var
      LSvgBrush: Vcl.Skia.TSkSvgBrush;
    begin
      LSvgBrush := Vcl.Skia.TSkSvgBrush.Create;
      try
        LSvgBrush.Source := TFile.ReadAllText(ASVGFile);
        LSvgBrush.Render(ACanvas, System.Types.RectF(0, 0, 100.0, 100.0), 1);
      finally
        LSvgBrush.Free;
      end;
    end);
finally
  bmp.Free;
end;

Can that be used to load the SVG file into the Bitmap?

The trick is that the Bitmap must be prepared before using SkiaDraw - setting the bitmap size, pixel format, transparent background color, etc.:
bmp := TBitmap.Create;

// Set the size of the bitmap to match the image list dimensions
bmp.Width := 100;
bmp.Height := 100;

// Set the PixelFormat to 32-bit for transparency
bmp.PixelFormat := pf32bit;

// Clear the bitmap with a transparent color
bmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := clNone;
bmp.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));

// If the image list supports transparency, the transparent parts of the image should remain transparent
bmp.Transparent := True;
try
  bmp.SkiaDraw(
    procedure(const ACanvas: System.Skia.ISKCanvas)
    var
      LSvgBrush: Vcl.Skia.TSkSvgBrush;
    begin
      LSvgBrush := Vcl.Skia.TSkSvgBrush.Create;
      try
        LSvgBrush.Source := TFile.ReadAllText(ThisTarget.Path);
        LSvgBrush.Render(ACanvas, System.Types.RectF(0, 0, 100.0, 100.0), 1);
      finally
        LSvgBrush.Free;
      end;
    end);
  CodeSite.Send('TForm1.MyThumbnailProvider: bmp', bmp);
finally
  bmp.Free;
end;

